# Codeigniter - URL rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I have a url: `http://localhost/mypay/admin/company/edit/profile`

Is it possible to make it more like a native fashion way:

```
http://localhost/mypay/admin/company/?edit=profile
```

I currently have a .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /mypay/

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Submitted by: Fabdrol
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

I've seen it to other sites and wanted it to be used in mine for easy readability. Thank you.

- james

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable the `$_GET` array, in config/config.php set these values:

```
$config['allow_get_array'] = TRUE;
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

In your controller you can then do:

```
$edit = $this->input->get('edit');
```